# Realm Object Server 2 dashboard inaccessible

Tags: npm, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've recently tried to install Realm Object Server from NPM (I'm on **macOS**). I was used to the Realm Dashboard which was embedded in the "macOS Bundle" available for the [1.x version](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/1.0/). It is unfortunately unavailable when attempting to reach `http://localhost:9080`.

There are now two things I think could be responsible for my issue:

1. This feature was only present in the 1.x version
2. This feature is not embedded in the NPM version

Please note that I'm using (or at least want to use) the **Developer Edition**.

I have been using ROS for a couple months now so I understand most of its functions but their subscription plans are very unclear because some features are supposed to be reserved to the Enterprise edition but on macOS you can temporarily have access to them for an unknown duration... Maybe what I'm looking for is no longer available ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web dashboard for Realm Object Server was removed in the 2.0 release. Instead, we moved most of the functionality into a new product: [Realm Studio](https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/). This is a cross-platform desktop application that combines the functionality from the web dashboard with functionality previously only available in our [macOS Realm Browser](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx).

We made this decision because we felt it was stronger for all of our users to unify the experience of working with Realm data in a UI. The 1.x version of Realm Object Server had a web data browser but it lacked features available in the macOS Realm Browser. With Realm Studio all functionality is available whether you are working with synced or non-synced local Realms.

Our focus will be entirely on Realm Studio going forward. It offers auto-updating so you can easily stay up-to-date as we add new functionality.

Comment: My bad then, thank you very much for that precision. I should have followed the roadmap more attentively !